# Node.js - write CSV file creates empty file in production, while OK in Mocha testing

Tags: node.js, stdin, fs, csv-write-stream

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/Muzietto/0c45d18335f8e0ea10020839592fb919) shows a code snippet that dumps an object into a CSV file.
File writing is done using module [csv-write-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-write-stream) and it returns a promise.

This code works flawlessly in all the Mocha tests that I have made.

When the code is invoked by the main nodejs app (a server-side REPL application involving raw `process.stdin` and `console.log` invocations as interaction with the user), the CSV file is created, but it's always empty and no error/warning seems to be thrown.

I have debugged extensively the REPL code with `node-debug` and the Chrome dev tools: I am sure that the event handlers of the WriteStream are working properly: no 'error', all 'data' seems to be handled, 'close' runs, the promise resolves as expected.

Nevertheless, in the latter case the file is always 0 bytes. I have checked several Q&A's and cannot find anything as specific as this.

My questions are:

- can I be missing some errors? how can I be sure to track all communications about the file write?
- in which direction could I intensify my investigation? which other setup could help me isolate the problem?
- since the problem may be due to the presence of `process.stdin` in the equation, what is a way to create a simple, light-weight interaction with the user without having to write a webapp?

I am working on Windows 7. Node 6.9.4, npm 3.5.3, csv-write-stream 2.0.0.

Comment: How do you test it? Are the testing conditions similar to how it's being used in the main app? You're using `process.stdin` in the main app, which is difficult to test with in Mocha, so perhaps there's an issue there? FWIW, [this blogpost](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/unit-testing-cli-programs/) describes how to mock `process.stdin`.

Comment: This is quite interesting. No, my tests are just exercising the code. Will try to include `process.stdin` mocking in the tests. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue in *two* ways, either by:

- resolving the promise upon the ['finish' event](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish) of the `FileWriteStream` rather than on the 'end' event of the `CSVWriteStream`
- removing the `process.exit()` I was using at the end of my operations with `process.stdin` (this implies that [this tutorial page](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/command-line/how-to-prompt-for-command-line-input/) may be in need of some corrections)